# How do I find the distance from the goal node named target, when I have the below mentioned start node named seeker?

Tags: python, path-finding, a-star

I am trying to find the distance from the start node named seeker to the goal node named target. I have already done most of the implementation of the algorithm and each of the nodes have a coordinate or box on a grid. My python code is lacking and I cannot find the coordinates and distance.

I have tried using the vector in the math class which gave me logical errors.
I also tried sending the actual objects hoping I could use those to reference the coordinates as I'd done in the code but got a TypeError: expected sequence object with len >= 0 or a single integer.

```html
import numpy as np
import pygame as pg
import sys
from Settings import *
from Sprites import *

vec = pg.math.Vector2


class Game:
    # initialise game window, etc
    def __init__(self):
        self.playing = True
        pg.init()
        self.mover = 'target'
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(Title)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        pg.key.set_repeat(500, 100)
        self.load_data()
        # pg.mouse.set_pos(0, 0)

        self.walls = []

        def load_data(self):
            pass

    # start a new game
    def new(self):
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self, 10, 10)
        self.target = Target(self, 5, 5)

    def load_data(self):
        pass

    # game loop
    def run(self):
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 10000
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def draw_grid(self):
        for x in range(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (x, 0), (x, HEIGHT))
        for y in range(0, HEIGHT, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (0, y), (WIDTH, y))

    def quit(self):
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def update(self):
        # game loop update
        self.all_sprites.update()

    def events(self):
        # game loop events
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()

            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mpos = vec(pg.mouse.get_pos()) // TILESIZE
                if event.button == 1:
                    if mpos in g.walls:
                        g.walls.remove(mpos)
                    else:
                        g.walls.append(mpos)

            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_b:
                    # start breadth first
                    breadthfirst(self.target, self.player, self.walls, self.screen)
                if event.key == pg.K_d:
                    # start depth first
                    depthfirst(self.target, self.player, self.walls, self.screen)
                if event.key == pg.K_a:
                    # start A* search
                    astarsearch(self.target, self.player, self.walls, self.screen)

                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.quit()

                if event.key == pg.K_t:
                    self.mover = 'target'
                if event.key == pg.K_s:
                    self.mover = 'seeker'

                if self.mover == 'target':
                    if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                        self.target.move(dx=-1)
                    if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                        self.target.move(dx=1)
                    if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                        self.target.move(dy=-1)
                    if event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                        self.target.move(dy=1)
                else:
                    if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                        self.player.move(dx=-1)
                    if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                        self.player.move(dx=1)
                    if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                        self.player.move(dy=-1)
                    if event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                        self.player.move(dy=1)

    def draw(self):
        # game loop - draw
        self.screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
        self.draw_grid()
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)

        for wall in self.walls:
            rect = pg.Rect(wall * TILESIZE, (TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
            pg.draw.rect(self.screen, GREEN, rect)

        # always do the flip after drawing everything
        pg.display.flip()

    def show_start_screen(self):
        # game splash/start screen
        pass

    def show_go_screen(self):
        # game over/continue screen
        pass

def breadthfirst(target, seeker, walls, maingrid):
    pass


def depthfirst(target, seeker, wall, maingrid):
    pass


def astarsearch(target, seeker, wall, maingrid):
    # array to store path locations
    direct_graph = {}

    # target location, returns a tuple
    target = np.where(target.pos) # problem area

    # seeker location, returns locations
    start = np.where(seeker.pos) # problem area

    # array of cost to travel so far
    g_cost_array = np.zeros(seeker) # problem area
    g_cost_array[start] = 0
    total_g_cost = 0

    # array for heuristic cost
    h_cost_array = np.zeros(seeker) # problem area

    # need to use a loop unfortunately...
    t = 0

    # possible steps
    steps = ((-1, 0), (+1, 0), (0, -1), (0, +1))

    for rows in h_cost_array:
        s = 0

        for cols in rows:
            # check if it's a wall! if not - get the distance to target
            loc = (t, s)

            if (maingrid[loc]):
                pass
            else:
                dist = abs(target[0] - s) + abs(target[1] - t)
                h_cost_array[t, s] = dist

            s += 1

        t += 1

    # total cost =  h + g
    f_cost_array = g_cost_array + h_cost_array

    # closed and open sets
    open_set = []
    open_set.append(start)

    closed_set = []

    # actual path
    path = []

    path.append([tuple(target[0]), tuple(target[1])])

    solution_found = False

    while (open_set):
        open_f_cost = []

        # get the heuristic cost for the candidates in the open set
        for vals in open_set:
            open_f_cost.append(f_cost_array[vals])

        # the shortest heuristic now
        # the index of the candidate with the lowest distance/heuristic
        best_dist_now = open_f_cost.index(min(open_f_cost))

        # the current best position
        best_pos_now = open_set[best_dist_now]

        # if the destination is reached, finish!
        if (tuple(best_pos_now) == target):
            solution_found = True
            break
        else:
            # remove the best guy from the open_set and add it to the closed set
            closed_set.append(open_set.pop(best_dist_now))
            # analyze the steps from the current best

            for step in steps:
                cand = (best_pos_now[0] + step[0], best_pos_now[1] + step[1])

                # check if there's a wall or beyond the screen
                if cand[0] < 0 or cand[1] < 0 or cand[0] > 39 or cand[1] > 23:
                    pass

                # skip this candidate because it's a wall!
                elif maingrid[cand]:
                    pass

                # need an else clause here to weed out the off-screen locations
                else:
                    # check if the candidate is in the closed set
                    already_seen = False
                    for dead in closed_set:
                        if np.all(dead == cand):
                            already_seen = True
                            break

                    # if the cell is in the closed set, skip it
                    if already_seen:
                        pass
                    else:
                        approx_g_score = g_cost_array[best_pos_now] + 1

                        # check if it's in the open list:
                        new = True
                        for others in open_set:
                            if np.all(others == cand):
                                new = False
                                break

                        # if a new cell or improved
                        if (new or approx_g_score < g_cost_array[cand]):
                            direct_graph[tuple(cand[0]), tuple(cand[1])] = (
                                tuple(best_pos_now[0]), tuple(best_pos_now[1]))
                            g_cost_array[cand] = approx_g_score
                            f_cost_array[cand] = g_cost_array[cand] + h_cost_array[cand]
                        if new:
                            open_set.append(cand)

    if not solution_found:
        return None
    else:
        recurrentPath(path, direct_graph, target, start)

        return path
# takes a dictionary as input
def recurrentPath(final_path, raw_path, dest, origin):
    a = raw_path[tuple(dest[0]), tuple(dest[1])]
    final_path.append(a)
    if (a != origin):
        recurrentPath(final_path, raw_path, a, origin)
    else:
        return final_path

g = Game()
g.show_start_screen()
while True:
    g.new()
    g.run()
    g.show_go_screen()

pg.QUIT
```

the expected results is to return the correct path to the target object from the seeker object after you press the keyboard character a. Note that with a left click, a wall can be constructed to add a hindrance to the seeking of the goal.

Comment: Please fix your indenting errors.

Comment: @LukeDeLuccia i fixed it... sorry the website refused for me to post the full code and kept cutting stuff off but i just used code insert